# Tiger geocoder ask for password for each step while downloading the data

Tags: postgis, geocoding, tiger

I'm downloading the data for geocoder with the respective scripts:

```
nation_script_load.sh    
ma_load.sh
```

The problem I'm having here is that for each of the files I asked to type the password, although the correct password is in the files:

```
WGETTOOL="/usr/bin/wget"          
export PGBIN="/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin"   
export PGPORT=5432
export PGHOST=localhost
export PGUSER=postgres            
export PGPASSWORD= "my_password"
```

I have tried by removing the quotes but isn't working either:

export PGPASSWORD= "my_password"
export PGPASSWORD= my_password